# How to obtain this expression in terms of real functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I know that this expression

```
(2 (ArcCot[E^(-((I ϕ)/2)) r] + ArcCot[E^((I ϕ)/2) r]))/π
```

is real, because is the sum of a real series, in particular:

```
Assuming[{r > 1, -π < ϕ < π, ϕ ∈ Reals}, Sum[r^-n 4/π Sin[n π/2]/n Cos [n ϕ/2], {n, 1, ∞}]] // FullSimplify

(2 (ArcCot[E^(-((I ϕ)/2)) r] + ArcCot[E^((I ϕ)/2) r]))/π
```

and I have been told that Maple gets a real function when calling `evalc`. But with `ComplexExpand` I do not get anything satisfying:

```
(2 (ArcCot[E^(-((I ϕ)/2)) r] + ArcCot[E^((I ϕ)/2) r]))/π // ComplexExpand
```

`-(Arg[1 - (I E^(-((I ϕ)/2)))/r]/π) + 
 Arg[1 + (I E^(-((I ϕ)/2)))/r]/π - 
 Arg[1 - (I E^((I ϕ)/2))/r]/π + 
 Arg[1 + (I E^((I ϕ)/2))/r]/π`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(*  "10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"  *)

expr = Assuming[{r > 1, -π < ϕ < π, ϕ ∈ 
     Reals}, Sum[
    r^-n 4/π Sin[n π/2]/n Cos[n ϕ/2], {n, 
     1, ∞}]] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

```
expr2 = Assuming[{r > 1, -π < ϕ < π, ϕ ∈ 
    Reals}, expr // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & //
    FullSimplify]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[#, {r, 1, 5}, {ϕ, -π, π}] & /@ {expr, expr2}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is completely satisfactory. It returns the result in terms of `Arg` which is always a real number. If look for its imaginary part

```
Im@ComplexExpand[(2 (ArcCot[E^(-((I \[Phi])/2)) r] + 
   ArcCot[E^((I \[Phi])/2) r]))/\[Pi]]
```

> 0

So your answer is a `Real` quantity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TargetFunctions` option of `ComplexExpand[]`:

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[(2 (ArcCot[E^(-((I ϕ)/2)) r] + ArcCot[E^((I ϕ)/2) r]))/π, 
                           TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], r > 1 && -π < ϕ < π]
   (2 (ArcCot[Sec[ϕ/2] (r + Sin[ϕ/2])] + ArcCot[r Sec[ϕ/2] - Tan[ϕ/2]]))/π
```

One could probably argue for the following further simplification, but you'll have to check if this remains valid for your assumptions:

```
2 ArcCot[TrigExpand[Cot[π %/2]] // Simplify]/π // Simplify
   2 ArcCot[(-1 + r^2) Csc[ϕ] Sin[ϕ/2]/r]/π
```